# Add Interactive Flow Arrows to Story Map

Tags: arcgis-online, story-map

Is it possible to add interactive arrows showing the movement of materials from one area to different sites?

The idea would be to create a story map showing the arrows (or something similar) at an overview and then the user would be able to click on each arrow separately which would direct them to a different page showing specific information about that facility.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an enhancement request for ArcGIS Online and its Story Map templates.

Consequently, if it is important to you I think you should post an [ArcGIS Idea](https://geonet.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas).